# How to sort call logs to international calls and local calls?

Tags: android

I am in the phase of developing an application on call logs. Before i dive into it I would want to get some information on this as I have read through the call logs class in Android Developer.

I want to know if there is a way that I can sort the call logs and sms and extract only international and local(Also the same with sms). Is it also possible that I accomplish this task by using third party Library like the Libphonenumber? If anyone has any code and suggestion that will help me I will be most grateful. I would appreciate a solution in the form of code or an advice on how i can accomplish this. I really do not want to get stuck half way when i start working on the project

This is the code I have to get the call logs for only outgoing calls

```
    managedCursor = managedQuery( CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,null, null,null, null);
    int number = managedCursor.getColumnIndex( CallLog.Calls.NUMBER ); 
    int type = managedCursor.getColumnIndex( CallLog.Calls.TYPE );
    int date = managedCursor.getColumnIndex( CallLog.Calls.DATE);
    int duration = managedCursor.getColumnIndex( CallLog.Calls.DURATION);


    while ( managedCursor.moveToNext() ) {

    String phNumber = managedCursor.getString( number );

    String callType = managedCursor.getString( type );
    String callDate = managedCursor.getString( date );
    Date callDayTime = new Date(Long.valueOf(callDate));
    String callDuration = managedCursor.getString( duration );

    int realdura=Integer.parseInt(callDuration);

    String dir = null;
    int dircode = Integer.parseInt( callType );
    if(dircode==CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE){
        dir="OutGoing Call";

    total_duration=realdura+total_duration;
    callList=("\nPhone Number:--- "+phNumber +" \nCall Type:--- "+dir+" \nCall Date:--- "+callDayTime+" \nCall duration in sec :--- "+callDuration);

    data.add(callList);
    }
    }

    managedCursor.close();

    call.setText("the total duration is: "+total_duration);
    list_data=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,data);
    call_list.setAdapter(list_data);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `libphonenumber` would seem to be a good idea to make things work internationally, there's a *lot* of country specifics in how they are represented.

What you need is the call [PhoneNumberUtil.parse](http://libphonenumber.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/i18n/phonenumbers/PhoneNumberUtil.html) (which I can't seem to link directly to), and pick the country_code out of the resulting PhoneNumber (documented [here in the example](https://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/)) That should allow you to just compare the country code to your local country code and easily know whether the call is international.

Here's a quick and dirty example (without error handling), "SE" is Sweden with international calling code "00" and country code "46" (ie the number is domestic and outputs that)

```
public static void main(String[] argv) throws NumberParseException {
    String str = "00468328999298";

    PhoneNumberUtil phoneNumberUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();

    Phonenumber.PhoneNumber number = phoneNumberUtil.parse(str, "SE");
    if(number.getCountryCode() != phoneNumberUtil.getCountryCodeForRegion("SE"))
        System.out.println("International");
    else
        System.out.println("Domestic");
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much. can you tell me which of the libphonenuber versions that i can add to my application?

Comment: @net_whiz I've never had trouble just going for the newest, that said I've only used it on Android 2.1 and newer.

Comment: @ Joachim Isaksson I am reading through the link you sent me and it looks good but can you please give me an example code that you have on how you implemented this so I can take a lead from there.

Comment: @net_whiz Added a usage example to the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Further more is there a way to know what country code the number was coz I saw that in parsing the numbers if the plus sign was not added it returns it as domestic whereas it is an international number.

Comment: Thanks I figured it out. I really appreciate your help.